# LocationListener not working on android device reboots in service class

Tags: android, location, android-service, background-service

I want to log the location of user every three seconds, I want to see the location when the app is killed and also if the user restart the device. I can see the location of user when the app is running or running in background

[image]

**My service:**

```
public class GPS_Service extends Service {

private LocationListener listener;
private LocationManager locationManager;

String bat;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        bat=String.valueOf(level) + "%";
    }
};
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.wtf("TAG", "Service created.");
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.wtf("TAG", "Service started.");

    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
            i.putExtra("coordinates",location.getLongitude()+" "+location.getLatitude()+ " " + bat);
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //noinspection MissingPermission
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,0,listener);
    return START_STICKY;
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(locationManager != null){
        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }
}
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.syyam.driverlocation">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".GPS_Service"/>
    <receiver
        android:name=".StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
        android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**My BroadcastReceiver:**

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, GPS_Service.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}}
```

Now, whenever I reboot my device I only see the logged messaged in my service **onCreate** and **onStartMethods**, but I cannot see the locations. My `log cat` is as follows after the reboot:

[image]

**EDIT: MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btn_start, btn_stop;
private TextView textView;
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(broadcastReceiver == null){
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                textView.setText("\n" +intent.getExtras().get("coordinates"));
                Log.wtf("hae"," "+intent.getExtras().get("coordinates"));
            }
        };
    }
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("location_update"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(broadcastReceiver != null){
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    if(!runtime_permissions())
        enable_buttons();

}

private void enable_buttons() {

    Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GPS_Service.class);
    startService(i);

}

private boolean runtime_permissions() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},100);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == 100){
        if( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            enable_buttons();
        }else {
            runtime_permissions();
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Where is the `Intent("location_update")` broadcast going? That is, which component do you have registering to receive it? If that component isn't running and registered, it's not going to get that broadcast.

Comment: I have a method onResume() in my mainActivity that is receiving it. I have added my mainActivity in the the Edit

Comment: OK, but at boot, your `MainActivity` isn't running, and therefore has no Receiver registered to get that broadcast.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am thinking. But is there any way I can run the mainActivity?

Comment: Well, technically, yes. You could `startActivity()` from the boot Receiver, like you are `startService()`, but do you really want to pop up your app at boot every time? Couldn't you do your logging in the `Service`?

Comment: Yes about to do that.